# Rsync create new file on file size change

Tags: backup, versioning, rsync, temporary-files

I need to backup (for debugging) some temporary files meanwhile a program running. I used to do it with `rsync`-ing the `/var/tmp/someprogram` directory with `find . -iname 'blahblah' -exec rsync -someoptions $DESTdir`, which works wonderful.

Except the case of someone in some program (for which I don't have source code access, and never will have - sad, and long story starting with COBOL...) overwrites the temporary file with new content from within the some program.

E.g.

1. Starting `PROG` program
2. This creates a `B1237` file in the `tmp` dir (and I'm `rsync`ing in every few minutes)
3. After the PROG finishes the processing of B123 it starts another cycle and recreates `B1237` with new content, and the `rsync`-ed file will be overwritten. And I need the first version as well.

Is it possible in an easy way? I was thinking about timestapped gzipping of the DEST dir, but there should be another way (without creating a (e.g.) `git` repo in the dest dir, and commiting after syncing...

**Update:** 
I did not mention - sorry - that I don't have the rights to install anything on this SLES9 (corporate) server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do something more space-efficient than `cp --archive`, you might want to look at `faubackup`.

Comment: rsync is much better for this as it first cheksums the files so it's more resource effective.